# Get second word from string in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get the second word of a sentence stored in a pandas column. I can easily get the first word with the following line:

```
df['First'] = df['Sentence'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.split()[0])
```

then why in the world trying to get the second word this way fails:

```
df['Second'] = df['Sentence'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.split()[1])
```

giving me

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `str.split` with `str[1]` and if no second word get `NaN`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sentence':['a','a d','s df sd']})
df['Second'] = df['Sentence'].astype(str).str.split().str[1]
print (df)
  Sentence Second
0        a    NaN
1      a d      d
2  s df sd     df
```

Explanation of error:

There is at least one sentence with no space, so selecting second value of list in `x.split()[1]` raise error, because second list does not exist.

Comment: Thank you so much jezrael, this is nice and simple, and fixes my problem. Still, I wonder what was wrong with my code.

Comment: @famargar - I think your code failed because at least one sentence with no space, so `x.split()[1]` failed.

Comment: impressively simple. I guess the only way my question can be helpful to other is if we integrate this information either in the question or the answer. I believe it's fairer you add this to your answer.

Comment: @Jezrael is there a way to retain the word if there is not two words?